# Send email from users account

Tags: sharepoint, email, moss, wss

In my sharepoint site I have a document library with a workflow attached to it.Once any user upload a new document workflow is started and the document is send to approver for approval along with this an email has been sent to the approver for new document pending for approval. Now then email is sent from the mail server I have configured in sharepoint. it works fine. Now my question is I want to send the email to the approver from users email ID so that the approver should know from whome the request is come from.

Can any one help me how can I configure mail server so that the outgoing emailing should be done from users email ID.

Thnaks 
sachin

Comment: Is this a SharePoint Designer, Native (web-based out of the box) or developed (custom code) workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set up a custom workflow with a custom activity to send the email rather than using the out of box approval workflow. This is one of those cases where a small change from the normal SharePoint way of doing things means a lot of extra work - the sort of problem I usually solve by telling the client it can't be done or is very expensive.

As an alternative, just including the requesting user name in the body of the email would be a lot easier and may be close enough to meeting the actual requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You have write an event handler for the document library. You will have to send the approval mail using this event handler instead of thw workflow.

[This post has some info abut event handlers in MOSS 2007](http://blogs.msdn.com/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/05/part-1-event-handlers-everything-you-need-to-know-about-microsoft-office-sharepoint-portal-server-moss-event-handlers.aspx)